# Высокая загрузка процессора на Mikrotik 2011

Tags: сеть, администрирование, mikrotik, маршрутизатор, сетевое-администрирование

Недавно я получил в свои руки Mikrotik 2011. Задача состояла в том, чтобы настроить его для небольшой корпоративной сети с примерно 50 клиентами. Для настройки я использовал Quick Set. Но, я заметил, что устройство сильно загружено, его процессор загружен в среднем на 17-24%, а иногда даже на 100%, тогда оно зависает и интернет пропадает. Как решить эту проблему?

Что мне дает провайдер:

- Статический IP
- IP-адрес DNS-сервера.

Порт ether1 - входящий порт, туда вставлен патч-корд от провайдера. Порты ether4, ether5 используются для подачи интернета в офис.

Как лучше всего снизить нагрузку на процессор и избежать дальнейших сбоев?

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Увидел что много запросов на 53 порт, решил закрыть его. Но это не помогло, видно, что пакетов и трафика прибавилось, но нагрузка остается довольно высокой.
[image]

[image]

Comment: убери блоклист.

Comment: @eri , я уже перенастроил фаерволл но особого результата не дало https://prnt.sc/24QUzX30NpsM